# Handwash on the go

Tags: camping, hygiene

I am searching for some time for a small "pocket soap" which does not require water.

Based on the comments below, there is basically:

1. Soap: Dissolves in water and helps to remove oils and dirt that's trapped within
2. Hand santizers that kill germs and bacteria

(combinations exist).

I love having (subjective) clean hands - hands that are not dirty, not sticky/oily and smelly. While I prefer not having bacteria and germs on my hands, feeling refreshed and not "sticky" is far more important than merely killing bacteria. Example: I touch smelly old metal parts, my bike grips or even steering wheel in the car and I have the strong desire to clean my hands. Or if I touch food. Or if I touch stuff I know it's used outside my "clean environment" like camping gear.

I tried many hand santizers but I don't feel having clean hands afterwards.

I also tried some wet wipes but the ones I tried didn't have a satisfactory effect either and furhtermore they are fairly bulky.

This is great: http://www.seatosummit.com/products/display/84 but it requires water.

What is the closest to washing hands with soap and water without water on the go?

Comment: The purpose of soap, chemically speaking, is to allow oil to be suspended in water, allowing it and any dirt trapped in it to be carried away by water. Without water or another solvent, soap doesn't actually clean anything. In environments where water is not readily available, hand sanitizing solutions (whether free or embedded in a towel) would be much better.

Comment: I can see that isn't there a solution which contains the water already (this is what I mean)? Particularly, I would like to apply it for sticky or smelly hands. If there is really nothing like that, could you provide a recommendation to a santizing solution that comes closest?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any recommendations, otherwise I would have left a full answer rather than a comment. You can find a basic overview at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_sanitizer .

Comment: I have tried waterless sanitizers from Bath and Body Works before, they work great.

Comment: Sanitizers and soaps serve entirely different purposes (which is why often soaps *include* sanitizers--because soap doesn't accomplish the same thing). What purpose do you want your "soap" to serve? To clean your hands, or to sanitize them? To make you feel refreshed?

Comment: The purpose should be "clean the hands" and "feel refreshed", in particular the hands should not be smelly and sticky. I usually do not use santizers because I do not feel so "clean"/"refreshed" afterwards. Therefore I asked for something similar to pocket soap rather than a santizer.

Comment: In fact normal soap sanitizes hands insofar as removing bacteria almost as much as antibacterial soap. Some regard the overhyping of antibacterial soaps as a bit of a con. I do not know if there are other "soaps that include sanitizers" than antibacterial soaps.

Comment: Be aware that many "refreshing towels" are very harmful to the environment. I'm not sure if there are also some environmentally friendly kinds, but I would try to find something like that if possible.

Comment: @divB: You should edit your question with some of the info in your comments clarifying that you're looking for clean=refreshed as a higher priority than clean=germ-free. (Not that the two are mutually exclusive.)

Comment: I don't understand the "no-water" requirement. I you intent to carry soap, why not a small bottle of water as well?

Comment: I thought of this but with conventional soap, as you may know it requires maybe 1/2 l of water to get everything off. I was hoping there is a solution that is basically water+soap but requiring only very little water and the water either evaporates on the clean hands or can be easily tried off on the pants or so ;)

Answer (score 3):

What you might be looking for are wet wipes.

In order for them to kill 99.9% of the bacteria, they need at least 70% alcohol.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You must **remove** dirt etc. from your hands to get them actually clean. Putting things on it can only at best kill microorganisms and it is not good for your skin. Simply use wet wipes or wet tissues if you have no soap and water, but really prefer the last one.

Comment: That may be too subjective for SE but in case, do you have a recommendation for super compact but good wet wipes? I tried some, currently I have "Wet Ones" from Safeway (US) but they are still bulky, the scent is far from comforting and after using them I still feel totally sticky and dirty.